# Do Keycloak Clients have a Client Secret?

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak

Does keycloak client id has a client secret? I tried to create a client in keycloak admin but I was not able to spot client secret.

Is it auto generated? Where can I get the secret?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

Your client need to have the `access-type` set to `confidential` , then you will have a new tab `credentials` where you will see the client secret.
https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_admin/topics/clients/oidc/confidential.html

Comment: The above link is not working.

Comment: FYI: for KC >v22 the label in the UI on the settings page is called "Client Authentication", see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69726692/405749

Answer (score 74):

Client need to have the `access-type` set to `confidential` and you can see the client Secret in credentials tab [image]

Answer (score 73):

> Does keycloak client id has a client secret? I tried to create a
> client in keycloak admin but I was not able to spot client secret.

First, you should know that Keycloak implements OpenID Connect, which

> [is a simple identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0 protocol.](https://openid.net/connect/)

According to the OAuth 2.0 protocol clients can be either **confidential** or **public**.

> The main difference relates to whether or not the application is able
> to hold credentials (such as a client ID and secret) securely.

Regarding the **confidential** clients:

> Because they use a trusted backend server, **confidential applications**
> can use grant types that require them to authenticate by specifying
> **their client ID and client secret** when calling the Token endpoint.

Armed with this knowledge you can easily create a client that will have a client secret as follows:

**OLD Keycloak UI**

1. Create a client with "Access Type" set to confidential:
   [image]
2. Click the Save button;
3. Afterwards a new tab named "Credentials" will show up :
   [image]
4. And there you can see the client secret:
   [image]

**NEW Keycloak UI**

1. Go to your realm and the Clients
2. Click on the button `Create` client

[image]

3. Set the `clientID`, and the remains fields accordingly and click `next`
4. Set the option `Client authentication` to `ON`
   [image]
5. Click on `Save`

To inspect the secret go to the clients > your client > tab `credentials`  and click on the `eye`

[image]

In my personal [Git repo](https://github.com/dreamcrash/StackOverflow-/tree/main/Keycloak/RestAdminAPI/Clients) you can find a script to extract the client secret. This script calls the endpoint

```
GET /{realm}/clients/{id}/client-secret
```

from the [Keycloak admin API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html).

Answer (score 18):

In keycloak version 20, access-type does not exist an as option.
If your client to be configured does not already have authentication on, set it on and then click save.

[image: Set Client authentication to On]

Your client will then have a "Credentials Tab" on the top, next to "Settings", "Keys", "Roles" etc.

[image: Credentials tab is now visible]

Click on the Credentials tab and your Client secret is found on that screen.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, each keycloak client has a client secret. But for this, you have to change the access type.
This differs from the keycloak version.
In specific versions, you have to change the **Access type** from **Public** to **Confidential**
In specific versions,  you have to **enable** the **Client authentication** under the Capability config.

[image: Client Authentication]

On saving this, you can see the credentials tab

You can copy the auto-generated client secret. You can also regenerate it any time

[image: Client secret]

Answer (score 0):

For me above mentioned step access-type tab not found.
What did work for me is:

1. Select your realm in my case "istiomesh"
2. Select "clients" tab in left bar
3. You may see two tabs "client list" and "Initial access token". Select later one and create Initial access token
   [image: Create client secret]

4. Copy that token and use as secret