# Where is the client_secret_key coming from?

Tags: python, keycloak

I have this basic code (using python-keycloak) for accessing Keycloak:

```
from keycloak import KeycloakAdmin


keycloak_admin = KeycloakAdmin(server_url="http://localhost:8080/auth/",
                               username='admin',
                               password='admin',
                               realm_name="master",
                               client_secret_key="client-secret",
                               verify=True)
```

Where can I find/set the client_secret_key in Keycloak?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does keycloak client ID has a secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44752273/does-keycloak-client-id-has-a-secret)

Answer (score 0):

Client secret key is available only for **confidential** & **bearer** only clients. So when you create a client. It has default public access type. So once you change your client "Access-Type" to "Confidential / Bearer Only", you should see credentials tab for that client. You can copy `client_secret` from there.

This is [@asthraa](https://github.com/asthraa) response, posted [here](https://github.com/marcospereirampj/python-keycloak/issues/79#issuecomment-621015862).