# Laravel Keycloak

Tags: laravel, keycloak

Help please with keycloak. Currently I am developing laravel app and authorize with keycloak. I have tried to do it with **socialiteproviders/keycloak** package. But for vain.

```
'keycloak' => [
  'client_id' => env('KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID'),
  'client_secret' => env('KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
  'redirect' => env('KEYCLOAK_REDIRECT_URI'),
  'base_url' => env('KEYCLOAK_BASE_URL'),   // Specify your keycloak server URL here
  'realms' => env('KEYCLOAK_REALM')         // Specify your keycloak realm
],
```

I got Client secret, but where is client id. **redirect** and **base_url**. I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

KEYCLOAK_BASE_URL = Url to your keycloack server - example: http://localhost:8080/auth
KEYCLOAK_REDIRECT_URI = Your Application Url for the redirect

for client secret see [Do Keycloak Clients have a Client Secret?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44752273/do-keycloak-clients-have-a-client-secret)