Keycloak infinite loop when logging in to react app
I use keycloak v26 in production, and the library "keycloak-js": "^26.0.0", i followed the keycloak docs for javascript adapter and this guys's youtube video, and i setup this simple React hook for authentication :
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';

const useAuth = () => {

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isLoggedIn, setisLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const client = new Keycloak({
      url: `${import.meta.env.VITE_KEYCLOAK_URL}`,
      realm: import.meta.env.VITE_KEYCLOAK_REALM,
      clientId: import.meta.env.VITE_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
    });
    
    console.log('client created', client);

    client.init({
      onLoad: 'login-required',
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log('res', res);
      setisLoggedIn(true);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    });

  }, []);

  return {isLoggedIn, isLoading};
}

export default useAuth

My problem is that my app enters an infinite loop as u can see here in the screenshots :

It sends this payload :

I followed the docs to the letter, someone explain please why it isnt working, what did i miss ? thanks in advance!

You need to use HTTPS because some vital cookies are blocked or rejected during authentication. This is due to the samesite cookie protection scheme that was added to browsers for a few years ago.
I have a blog post about troubleshooting and seeing why cookies are blocked or rejected here: Debugging cookie problems.

I have Keycloak running in https ( in producation mode) , hence the 8443 port, but i selfsigned the certificate, and the browser doesn't like that, maybe that's what causes the error ?

The browsers would complain if there was a certificate error, I saw some http://localhost:5173 in the image in the question. However, there is also the communication between containers and the communication between the browsers and Keycloak and the client application. You should use a trusted certificate in keykloak, so the browser is happy. It is a bit messy, with the private and public communication channels and their different needs.

Your error seems to be a 401 error when the client posts the auth code to the tokenendpoint to retrieve the tokens, could it be the client id and secret is wrong?

By following the docs and the guide on youtube, they haven't used any secret, i agree that the setup i made is messy, it's keycloak container running on ec2 in production with a locally installed postgres db, with a self-signed certificate, while i work on the cert, if u have useful links i can use that explain how to implement this using the client secret as well ? thanks

See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44752273/do-keycloak-clients-have-a-client-secret
